# Fix for HTTPClient::ConnectionTimeoutError while using the Ruby google-client-api gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

With the google-api-client gem I am able to create the CivicInfoService object and I am using the function `civic_info.representative_info_by_address(address: 80202, levels: 'country', roles: ['legislatorUpperBody', 'legislatorLowerBody'])` to access data from the api. However, when I run it, it stalls for 60 seconds and then displays this error message:

```
> /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:611:in `initialize': execution expired (Google::Apis::TransmissionError)
> from /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:611:in `new'
> from /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:611:in `create_socket'
> from /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/ssl_socket.rb:21:in `create_socket'
> from /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:752:in `block in connect'
> from /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/timeout.rb:189:in `block in timeout'
> from /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/timeout.rb:196:in `timeout'
> from /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:748:in `connect'
> from /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:511:in `query'
> from /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:177:in `query'
> from /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1242:in `do_get_block'
> from /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1019:in `block in do_request'
> from /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1133:in `protect_keep_alive_disconnected'
> from /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1014:in `do_request'
> from /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1104:in `follow_redirect'
> from /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:854:in `request'
> from /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/google-apis-core-0.11.1/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:313:in `execute_once'
> 16 levels...
> /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:611:in `initialize': execution expired (HTTPClient::ConnectTimeoutError)
> from /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:611:in `new'
> from /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:611:in `create_socket'
> from /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/ssl_socket.rb:21:in `create_socket'
> from /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:752:in `block in connect'
> from /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/timeout.rb:189:in `block in timeout'
> from /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/timeout.rb:196:in `timeout'
> from /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:748:in `connect'
> from /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:511:in `query'
> from /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:177:in `query'
> from /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1242:in `do_get_block'
> from /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1019:in `block in do_request'
> from /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1133:in `protect_keep_alive_disconnected'
> from /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1014:in `do_request'
> from /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1104:in `follow_redirect'
> from /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:854:in `request'
> from /home/blainefreestone/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/google-apis-core-0.11.1/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:313:in `execute_once'
```

I have tried to update the way my virtual linux machine connects to the internet as the connection seems to be the issue but that didn't work. I am able to access the internet and the api on my web browser without any issues. I believe it must have something to do with the installation of ruby or the gem.

Are there any ideas of what I could do to try and fix this?

Comment: Can you test that *any* API works? Then test that you can connect to that service using, say, `curl` from that VM.